# Cross dekstop/mobile authentication in HTML5 game (Facebook, Google, Twitter with oauth)

Tags: html, node.js, backbone.js, cordova, oauth

me and my friend are thinking of developing kickass Html5 multiplayer game. Our developer dream is launch one codebase (as far it's possible) to iOS, Android and desktop browser.

We're thinking about creating whole game (client side) as a single page aplication in BB (managing views, api calls, canvas etc.). Then publishing on www server as a casual site or wrapping though PhoneGap to publish on mobiles.

Backend stack so far includes:

- Node,
- Express (game api),
- Mongo,
- Socketio
- PassportJs with extensions

Frontend:

- Backbone with Marionette
- PixiJs (for canvas rendering), maybe Cocoonjs for boosting
- PhoneGap (??? it's just a wrapper with some additional libs from I've read)

How do you handle different authentication policies at cross platform environment. As Google Play, AppStore are only distribution system, we need to login Facebook, Google+ or Twitter on our own and stay away from i.e PhoneGap-social as it works only when publishing on mobile. Am I right?

If we go with BB and spa, we should not reload the page, so how to show FB/G+/T authorization popup in front and route params in background from client app to server when logged in?

What are the best practices to make it authentication universal, what's your experience?

Comment: this might help http://madhatted.com/2014/6/17/authentication-for-single-page-apps  Plus I implemented Facebook and Twitter OAuth using a pop-up and as far as I have tested it works fine on safari on iOS, as it opens a new tab and functions as on desktop, I am using the same backend stack as yours except for socketio.

Comment: Thank you Nimgrg for those hints, in fact it looks that I should show i.e. facebook auth in modal box and then intercept the response and route it to the server by api...